# C#: Difference between using System.Text and System.Text.RegularExpressions

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET C# application, I noticed in order to use Regex and StringBuilder, I had to put both

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

From looking at this plainly, I would think `using System.Text` might include `RegularExpressions`, but both are necessary. What is the difference between those two?

Comment: It's different namespaces with different sets of classess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different namespaces with different classes. Including the top level namespace (`System.Text`) doesn't *mean* that namespace below *(like RegularExpression)* will be added.

`StringBuilder` is from `System.Text` so that is why you need `using System.Text;` and `Regex` is from `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and that is why you need that as well.

See: [using directive from C# Specifications section 9.4.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

> The scope of a using-directive extends over the
>   namespace-member-declarations of its **immediately containing**
>   compilation unit or namespace body. The scope of a using-directive
>   specifically does not include its peer using-directives. Thus, peer
>   using-directives do not affect each other, and the order in which they
>   are written is insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

- `Regex` is defined in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`
- `StringBuilder` is defined in `System.Text`

You need to include both namespaces for these two types to be in scope. Including a namespace `A.B` doesn't automatically include a contained namespace `A.B.C`. If this were the case, nested namespaces would be of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> The `System.Text` namespace contains classes that represent ASCII and
>   Unicode character encodings; abstract base classes for converting
>   blocks of characters to and from blocks of bytes; and a helper class
>   that manipulates and formats String objects without creating
>   intermediate instances of String.

And:

> The `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace contains classes that
>   provide access to the .NET Framework regular expression engine. The
>   namespace provides regular expression functionality that may be used
>   from any platform or language that runs within the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. In addition to the types contained in this namespace, the
>   System.Configuration.RegexStringValidator class enables you to
>   determine whether a particular string conforms to a regular expression
>   pattern.

`StringBuilder` lives in the `System.Text` namespace and `Regex` lives in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. These namespaces are just logical separators, and including a parent namespace doesn't automatically include children, and vice versa.